# Task assigning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, variable-assignment

I'm trying to figure out what the most efficient way of assigning tasks to people. Here is what I'm struggling with:

- you have X number of people that are all eligible to do work
- each person can do X number of tasks at once
- you have X number of waiting tasks
- each task takes a variable length of time

The goal of the challenge is to evenly distribute the tasks among the people as best as possible. Once a person finishes one of the given tasks, one of the 'queued' tasks will be fed to them. Here's an example scenario.

There's 500 tasks in the queue with 50 people available to 'take' them. Each person can take 2 tasks at once. Once a person finishes a given task they'll be fed another. The tasks that have been waiting the longest get the highest priority.

One way to possibly do it would be to have each of the 50 people that have the capacity to take a task be assigned one based on their task last given time. For example:

- task 1 -> person 1
- task 2 -> person 2
- task 3 -> person 3

...

- task 4 -> person 1
- task 5 -> person 2
- task 6 -> person 3

Based on the task last assigned to X person, the person with the oldest task last assigned and that's available to take on another task would get it fed to them. I'm unsure if this is the right solution for even task distribution, would love to hear suggestions! Is there a name for this type of algorithm?

Another method could possibly be to assign tasks based on the person currently serving the lowest number of tasks. Although if multiple people are tied to for the lowest number of tasks, the task is assigned to the person who's been available (last task assigned) for the longest period of time.

Comment: Is each worker equivalent, or are some capable of doing more tasks than others?

Comment: Some are capable of doing more. @catalogue_number

Comment: Also, do you know all the tasks in advance, or do they arrive dynamically?

Comment: They arrive dynamically. At 10:00 there could be 10 queued, at 10:05 there could be 30.

Comment: What do you mean by 'evenly distribute'? Are you looking to share out the tasks so that the workers spend roughly equal time working, or is the goal to end up with the same number of tasks done?

Comment: These kinds of algorithms are called [scheduling algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29). There is a lot you can read about them.

Comment: @catalogue_number evenly distribute meaning that the goal is to have all people working on the same number of tasks at once, as consistently as possible. It doesn't matter if person A finishes a task before person B, the goal is for them to consistently keep their 'currently working on tasks' the same number so that everyone doing tasks will always be doing the same number of tasks at once.

Comment: @DavidZ yea I read a bit about them. I'm struggling to decide on what would be the best for even distribution for this use case. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "most efficient". What is wrong with the solution of assigning the next task to any free worker? It seems like your problem is unclear requirements rather than programming or algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider looking at this at a higher level.

The proposals so far have been greedy. They build one schedule and hope for the best.

The first thing you'll need to decide is whether that's what you want. Greedy assignment will produce spectacularly bad answers for some inputs, though if the inputs are "reasonable," and all you want is a reasonable answer, it may be fine.

On the other hand, finding *the* optimal assignment of tasks is NP hard. You'll need time exponential in the input size to be sure you have the best possible answer.

There are two intermediate approaches.

- Randomized task scheduling algorithms. This is a huge topic.  [This paper](http://www.immorlica.com/randAlg/Karp91.pdf) is still a decent starting place, though it's now very out-of-date. Richard Karp is amazing. The nice thing about randomized algorithms is that they can provide very useful optimality guarantees.
- Heuristic search. Define a single numeric metric of goodness of a schedule. Start with a reasonable one (greedily determined or random). Put that on the search queue sorted by metric v, pull the best metric off the queue, find all its "children", i.e. schedules that haven't been considered before resulting from all possible simple changes, add these to the queue, and repeat. Stop when you can't wait any longer. The current best is your answer. You can also structure this as a genetic algorithm, which is just a specialized heuristic search.

Answer (score 0):

Keep 2 queues. one for tasks another for free people waiting for task. If there is a task to be taken first person from queue will take and go. You will not think about time for tasks and people in this solution as it is justice way of distribution. You might think about priority queues if you need some kind of prioritization in the future with little changes for both queues.

Answer (score 0):

As zsiar, but use two priority queues. The top task in the top priority queue gets assigned to the top workers, assuming he is capable. If he's not, the task can't be done and must wait.

Workers in the worker priority queue get ordered by capacity or time idle or whatever seems fair. In fact it's not a real priority queue as when a worker finishes a task, we take him out and put him back in the queue, in a higher position.

(If workers can do two tasks at once they are probably computers rather than people, so time idle isn't a useful metric. Only human workers care if they are kept busy whilst other doss about).